# GtkButton to emit GDK_KEY_PRESS

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm attempting to attach to a toolbar button a signal associated with a keystroke supported by GtkTextView (CTRL+a, CTRL+x, etc) using the following widget structure, signal connect, and callback:

```
typedef struct
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *text_view;
}EditorWidgets;

//...

    g_signal_connect(cut, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(cut_button_press), editor_widgets);

//...

static void cut_button_press(GtkWidget *button, EditorWidgets *editor_widgets)
{
    UNUSED(button);

    GdkEvent *event = gdk_event_new(GDK_KEY_PRESS);

    event->key.window = gtk_widget_get_window(editor_widgets->window);
    event->key.send_event = FALSE;
    event->key.time = 0;
    event->key.state = GDK_CONTROL_MASK;
    event->key.keyval = GDK_KEY_x;
    event->key.string = g_strdup("x");
    event->key.length = strlen(event->key.string);

    gtk_main_do_event(event);

    gdk_event_free(event);
}
```

When run, GDK complains with the following:

```
(ex1:7856): Gdk-WARNING **: Event with type 8 not holding a GdkDevice. It is most likely synthesized outside Gdk/GTK+
```

Which lets me know I've created the signal improperly (I assume). However, there's very little out there about having buttons emit GDK signals, so I'm at a loss for what's missing here.

As a secondary question, I remember reading somewhere that there was a GDK `#define` for `TIME_NOW` or something, but I couldn't find it again. Any hints there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.use "key-press-event" instead of clicked, clicked was associated with mouse pointer and keyboard enter key, something like (in python):

```
   def on_key_press (self, widget, event):
       if event.keyval == 120:
          print ('test')
```

2.GDK_CURRENT_TIME, define at Gdk.Event class

Comment: key-press-signal generates the following: (ex1:10415): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:2462: signal 'key-press-signal' is invalid for instance '0x1e328a0' of type 'GtkToolButton' while key-press-event just does nothing and doesn't complain.

Comment: But GDK_CURRENT_TIME worked, of course. =) Thank you.